# Get all Accounts associated with Opportunity Using Flow Builder

Tags: flow-builder

I will like to get all Accounts that have at least one Opportunity associated with and then mass update a field of the Accounts. I will like to use Flow Builder. Please any idea???

Comment: welcome to SFSE, please see [ask] for getting the most from the community. Some specific research is required in order to get the best attention from the Community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm..

How about creating a rollup summary field on Account to store count of Opportunities and then using Get Records in Flow builder to pull all Accounts which have this roll up field value >=1.

I think this should work.

Comment: Thanks Angad, Ich created at Rollup Summary field in Account with "COUNT" as Roll-Up Type and "Opportunity" as Summerized Object. In my Get Element in the Flow, I put this conditions:  "rollup field name"  Is Greater Than 0. This help me to get all Accounts that are associated with an Opportunity.